# How to auto generate web forms?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview, webforms

Using Asp.net 4.0 and visual studio 2010.
I have a database and a table to insert news in it and i have made a page(WebForm) to insert information to my news table. I have another page that there is a grid view in it and this gridview show all contents from news table and now what i want to do is to when for example when an admin wants to insert news , so then a page will be created and all the informations that he has inserted will be diplayed in the generated or auto created page. 
Also in the gridview beside any rows that are displayed from the news table i want to display a hyperlink that will redirect the page to the page with the selected row information (in the page that i already generate i mean).
Can anybody help?!

Here's my gridview code :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="187px" CellPadding="4" 
EnableTheming="True" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" PageIndex="1" 
PageSize="5" ShowFooter="True" 
    >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BorderColor="White" BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <div style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
                </div>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="gridview" 

                    style="border-color: #FFFFFF; border-style: none; width: 924px; height: 141px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;" 
                    align="right" dir="ltr">
                    <table class="auto-style1">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="style2">
                                <table class="auto-style1">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            &nbsp;</td>
                                        <td style="text-align: left">
                                            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="180px" 
                                                ImageUrl='<%# Eval("IMG") %>' Width="193px" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" 
                                                BorderStyle="Solid" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            &nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <table class="auto-style1">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="style9">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Names="Microsoft Uighur" 
                                                Font-Size="X-Large" Text='<%# Eval("Fname") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="style3">
                                            : نام</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="style9">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Font-Names="Microsoft Uighur" 
                                                Font-Size="X-Large" Text='<%# Eval("Lname") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="style3">
                                            : نام خانوادگی</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="style9">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Font-Names="Microsoft Uighur" 
                                                Font-Size="X-Large" Text='<%# Eval("Major") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="style8">
                                            : رشته تدریس</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="style9">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Font-Names="Microsoft Uighur" 
                                                Font-Size="X-Large" Text='<%# Eval("EnFname") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="style3">
                                            : نام لاتین</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="style5">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Font-Names="Microsoft Uighur" 
                                                Font-Size="X-Large" Text='<%# Eval("EnLname") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="style3">
                                            : نام خانوادگی با لاتین</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="style9">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Font-Names="Microsoft Uighur" 
                                                Font-Size="X-Large" Text='<%# Eval("EnMajor") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="style3">
                                            : رشته تدریس به لاتین</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <EmptyDataRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <div style="height: 115px; width: 914px">
            No data to display<br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <PagerTemplate>
        <div style="height: 131px; ">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Fname") %>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Lname") %>'></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </PagerTemplate>
    <RowStyle BorderColor="White" BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Means display news details in other page. right?

Comment: No , I mean When someone insert a news a page be automatically created And the data what have been inserted be displayed in the created page...

Comment: Means when you click on grid view row to redirect other page and display selected row data on this page ?

Comment: So no need to generate dynamic page. You can do in single page using query string concept.

Comment: Well How should i do that?

Comment: Put your gridview code in your question.

Comment: Ok now what should i do?

Comment: my answer is help you or not?

Comment: See my comment in your answer there is a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href='NewsDetail.aspx?newsId=<%# Eval("NewsId") %>'>    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="180px"  ImageUrl='<%# Eval("IMG") %>' Width="193px" BorderColor="#CCCCCC"                                                 BorderStyle="Solid" /></a>
```

On NewsDetail.aspx page.

You can Get news id like below:

```
int newsid= convert.ToInt32(Request.Querystring["newsId"]);
```

After bind data based on news id on details page. On every row click you can get different news id.

Comment: Ok I have created a webform and in the page_load i have typed this code : `int newsid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["NewsId"]);
        Label1.Text = newsid.ToString();`

Comment: But i get this error : **Input string was not in a correct format.**

Comment: In my gridview item template i have put a hyperlink and the text of the hyperlink i the news title and when you click on it it will redirect you to the page NewsDetail.aspx here's my code: ` **<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink112" runat="server" 
                                        NavigateUrl='~/Admin/NewsContentPage.aspx?NewsId=<%# Eval("NewsId") %>' Text='<%# Eval("NewsTitle") %>'></asp:HyperLink>`**

Comment: My Question Solved Thanks